# GCP BigQuery shows "This script will process 2TB when run" for a simple query with "limit 10"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When I select my query for a large partition table in GCP BigQuery,

```
select * from <myBQtable> limit 10;
```

I haven't clicked "Run" button yet and it told me "This script will process 2TB when run."

I wonder why a "limit 10" query will still have this big cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With BigQuery, you pay for the volume of data that you scan, not that you get. You have different way to optimize the volume of data that you query with [partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) and [clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables).

But also, by avoiding to get ALL the column (`select *`), but by selecting only the relevant column (BigQuery has a column oriented storage and if you don't mention a column you don't load/scan it). You have [guidelines to save cost in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/cost-optimization-best-practices-for-bigquery)

Answer (score 2):

`LIMIT` is not used to control costs in BigQuery. It only reduces the total time taken to display the results.

So for `SELECT * FROM [table] LIMIT 10`, the query will read the whole table but display only 10 rows.

Comment: Thanks.
I wonder if GCP should consider improving the implementation on such query?
I just wanted to do a quick smoke on the data.
I know BQ provides schema and preview tools.

Comment: BigQuery SQL queries uses Standard SQL; in which the LIMIT used to display limited rows, however query will be scanning  the entire table. That is why BQ is showing 2 TB for you. If you just want to see the data, preview tools are appropriate as you said. Otherwise, partitioning-clustering is the best option to limit the amount of data scanned by Query.